# Could not find aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows.jar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm traying to run my app in android studio but I have this error:

```
    Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
   > Could not find aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:4.1.3-6503028).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/4.1.3-6503028/aapt2-4.1.3-6503028-windows.jar

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

My build.gradle is:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried toggle offline mode but I have same error. and I can download it manually from the link in the error but in android studio not